# Unable to compile with cx_freeze and PySide2

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyside2

I have a python program I'm trying to compile with cx_freeze. The GUI I'm using is PySide2.

I've tried including PySide2, here is excluding it, but I keep getting the same error.  Below is my setup.py code

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


includefiles = ['README.md', 'debug.log','tcl86t.dll', 'tk86t.dll', 'field.jpg', 'inputClass.py', 'mainfile.qml', 'MyTabView.qml', 'PlayerSelection.qml', 'selectedPlayers.py', 'Settings.qml', 'SimOutput.qml', 'simulationOutput.py']

includes = ["idna.idnadata", "atexit"]

excludes = ["PySide2"]

import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\pimat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\pimat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'


setup(name = "Simulation",
      version = "0.2",
      description = "Optimization Simulator",
      options = {'build_exe':{'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'include_files':includefiles}},
      executables = [Executable("main.py")])
```

The program compiles fine, but when running the exe, I get the following error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the error was that I had installed cx_freeze with python 3.6, but all of my packages were in a python 3.7 folder. I simply copied and pasted into the 3.6 folder and changed the code a bit, and the exe works great.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


# dependencies
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "sys", "re", "idna.idnadata", "atexit", "PySide2.QtCore", "PySide2.QtWidgets", "PySide2.QtUiTools", "PySide2.QtQuick", "PySide2.QtQml", "PySide2.QtGui", "shiboken2"],
    "include_files": ['README.md', 'debug.log','tcl86t.dll', 'tk86t.dll', 'field.jpg', 'inputClass.py', 'mainfile.qml', 'MyTabView.qml', 'PlayerSelection.qml', 'selectedPlayers.py', 'Settings.qml', 'SimOutput.qml', 'simulationOutput.py',
               ], 
    "excludes": ["Tkinter", "Tkconstants", "tcl", ],
    "build_exe": "build",
    #"icon": "./example/Resources/Icons/monitor.ico"
}

executable = [
    Executable("main.py",
               base="Win32GUI",
               targetName="Simulation.exe"
               )
    ]



setup(name = "Simulation",
      version = "0.2",
      description = "Simulator",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=executable
      )
```

T'was a dumb mistake, but I've made worse