# cx_Freeze built GUI application(PySide2) fail to run

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyside2

I want to create exe file with cx_Freeze for python/PySide2 script.
python source

```
#!/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import PySide2.QtWidgets as QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

mainwindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
mainwindow.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

label = QtWidgets.QLabel(mainwindow)
label.setText('Hello World!!')
label.parent().layout().addWidget(label)

mainwindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this script run as python argument, completely as i expected.

cx_Freeze setup.py (customized on cxfreeze-quickstart output)

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import platform

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(
    packages = [],
    excludes = [],
    includes = [],
)

base = 'Console'
if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
  base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('sayHelloGUI.py', base=base, targetName = 'GreetingsGUI')
]

setup(name='SayHello',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'print greetings',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

building itself finished successfully, but execution show me error dialog like this:
[image]

How can i solve this problem?
Python 3.7 / cx_Freeze 6.1 / Windows 10

Comment: Can you try adding 'Pyside2.QtWidgets' to the packages list in the build options?

Comment: I tried both "packages = ['PySide2.QtWidgets']"and "includes=['Python2.QtWidgets']" but still showing the message dialog.
Log says cx_Freeze copy PySide2 files on build directry, and surely those are there...

Comment: can you check if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135147/unable-to-compile-with-cx-freeze-and-pyside2) works?

Comment: I don't have python 3.6, but have debris in Python 2.7 directory after uninstall it, so i remove it all, and check system (and my) environment variables, and reinstall cx_Freeze and PySide2 via pip, then restart my computer. Then, copy & paste "solution"'s setup.py, modify it for my scripts.
.... but the dialog is still shown and failed to run...

Comment: I found the reason to fail, path for my working directory including Japanese character. I moved it to directory where the path is only ascii characters, then window appeared properly on executing..

Comment: nice work! you can write that as an answer and accept it for others to see